# Calcular porcentagem

Tags: c#, .net, matemática, porcentagem

```
Largura * Complemento = Subtotal + Porcentagem = Total

subtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(largura.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(complemento.Text)).ToString();
total.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(subtotal.Text) % Convert.ToDouble(PercaTextBox3.Text)).ToString();
```

Onde estou errando a porcentagem?

Comment: `Largura * Complemento = Subtotal + Porcentagem = Total` é uma formula? Isso não faz parte do código não é?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

O símbolo de porcentagem não calcula a porcentagem, tem que usar a matemática básica para fazer isso. Alias sugiro aprender a programar de forma mais estruturada. Aprender na tentativa e erro sem saber o que está fazendo é mais difícil, mesmo que não pareça, gasta mais tempo, pula coisas importantes, e principalmente ensina errado causando tragédias.

Tem um erro extra no seu código que vou aproveitar para resolver. A conversão de dado vindo externamente não é garantida e pode quebrar sua aplicação, você tem que ter certeza que foi digitado algo que pode ser convertido.

Eu fiz em Console porque é mais fácil demonstrar, mas você adapta para Windows Forms. Até fiz uma última conversão para `string` que só fará sentido no Windows Forms.

Tem conversões sem sentido no código. Por isso reforço para entender o que está fazendo, na forma atual não está aprendendo programar. Uma frase que sempre digo:

> Se você não sabe tudo o que seu código faz, inclusive o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar

```
using static System.Console;
    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var larguraText = "2.00";
        var alturaText = "1.00";
        var percText = "30";
        var total = 0.0;
        if (double.TryParse(larguraText, out var largura) && double.TryParse(alturaText, out var altura) && double.TryParse(percText, out var perc)) {
            total = largura * altura * (perc / 100);
        }
        var totalText = total.ToString(); //só para fins didáticos do exemplo
        WriteLine(totalText);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/h7juUr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cKqTvS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Percent.cs).